# Machine learning to classify company names to their industries

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, multilabel-classification

What I'm trying to do is to ask the user to input a company name, for example Microsoft, and be able to predict that it is in the Computer Software industry. I have around 150 000 names and 60+ industries. Some of the names are not English company names.

I have tried training a Word2Vec model using Gensim based on company names only and averaged up the word vectors before feeding it into SKlearn's logistic regression but had terrible results. My questions are:

1. Has anyone tried these kind of tasks? Googling on short text classification shows me results on classifying short sentences instead of pure names. If anyone had tried this before, mind sharing a few keywords or research papers regarding this task?
2. Would it be better if I have a brief description for each company instead of only using their names? How much would it help for my Word2Vec model rather than using only the company names?

Comment: You can try using neural networks with a  `softmax` output layer to do the classification, since you've already gotten the word vectors by neural networks. You can also train the word embedding layers simultaneously with the classification layers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'training word embedding layers simultaneously with the classification layers?' @Huang

Comment: Build a network with a). Input layer (company name or description). b).word embedding layers and c). `softmax` output (classification) layers. Then train the network by the industries(as class labels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your problem, This is nothing but Company-Industry Relationship so for that, you have to train your word2vec [model](https://github.com/llSourcell/word_vectors_game_of_thrones-LIVE) using company description data because the word2vec works on calculating the similar words related to the given word.So if you train, based on the company names that would give you bad results.If you train on the description then that would give you the similar words related to the particular industry.By using that you can get the industry it belongs to.

If you want to train based on company names NER(Named Entity Tagger) will be useful.But this will not be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want.

If the point is to use just company names, maybe break names into syllables/phonemes, and train on that data.

If the point is to use Word2Vec, I'd recommend pulling the Wikipedia page for each company (easier to automate than an 'about me').

Comment: I removed the 'about me' part because I didn't want to stress on how I get the data. Would a Word2Vec model trained on the company description be better than a Word2Vec model trained by the syllables?

Comment: @AyynonNimusTraining a word2vec model based on company descriptions will be good.because with that you can capture the context of the company name usage such that you will get the industry it belongs to.Please check my answer.